# Get the Battery status on windows 8

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, battery, batterylevel

I searched over the Internet and the only thing that I found a little bit helpful was the way to get Battery status on Windows Phone 8. But I want it on Windows 8 (RT).

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to everything that I can find, we do not have access to the Power API in WinRT, it is only available for a desktop application. See this [MSDN Forum article](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithnativecode/thread/63be5227-a1e1-43f2-8650-c861f0912b72)

From above link:

> Power Management Functions apply to "desktop app only".
>
> No equivalent for the Power APIs in Metro style app. [Please check Alternatives to Windows APIs in Metro style apps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464945.aspx)
>
> Here is another thread http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/tailoringappsfordevices/thread/3e9dc84c-bbf9-42f3-bc19-25bce3e7e04c for your reference.

Comment: How they want to be competitive in mobile market when they don't provide such basic apis?

Comment: @Vistritium This was the case for Win-RT, it is available in the Windows Phone 8 api.

Comment: It won't be for a Metro App, just Desktop.